# Volume calculation of different termite mouts

Tags: qgis, volume

So i know how to calculate the volume of 1 indiviual mountain, but my problem is that i have a data set (LiDAR) with a lot of those. I was thinking if there was a more effecient way to calculate the volumes.

I made a pointcloud in Agisoft Metashape, then moved it to cloudcompare as a .las file, then made a DEM and DTM and moved it to QGIS and calculated a nDSM with contours.

2 things i think of if possible:

- Is it possible to extract the mounts based on the height (i made the DTM so every mount has a comparable starting hight.
- Can you calculate the mounts separate (if i try it now it just gives me 1 total volume)

If anyone thinks of a better way let me know.

[image: the screenshot is a small area from QGIS, there is a lot more]